# Gson fromJson only loading 1 element of ArrayList in object

Tags: android, json, gson

I have an `ArrayList<CustomClass>` inside of `ParentClass` which I have written to a file using `Gson.toJson()`.  However when I try to de-serialize the JSON using `Gson.fromJson()` I only get 1 element of the `ArrayList<CustomClass>`.

For example I will do the following

```
public class ParentClass {
    private ArrayList<CustomClass> myList = new ArrayList<CustomClass>();

    private GrandParentClass nested;

    public ParentClass() {
        myList.add(new CustomClass("adsf"));
        myList.add(new CustomClass("fdsa"));

        nested = new GrandParentClass();
    }

    public int arraySize() {
        return myList.size();
    }
}

public class GrandParentClass {
    private ArrayList<OtherCustomClass> myList = new ArrayList<OtherCustomClass>();

    public GrandParentClass() {
        myList.add(new CustomClass("asdfasdf.."));
        myList.add(new CustomClass("fdsafdsa..."));

    }

    public int arraySize() {
        return myList.size();
    }
}
```

Then when I instantiate a new instance of ParentClass, I use the following to write it to a file.

```
ParentClass pc = new ParentClass();
Gson gson = new Gson();
String writeThis = gson.toJson(pc); // Produces a perfect JSON reflection myList

FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(new File("writeto.json"));
fos.write(writeThis);
fos.close();
```

The JSON object is written in plain text to the .json file

```
FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(new File("writeto.json"));
char c;
StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
while ((c = fis.read()) != -1)
    sb.append((char) c);

//Now this is where I only get 1 element of the ArrayList
Gson gson = new Gson();
ParentClass pc = gson.fromJson(sb.toString(), ParentClass.class);

Log.i("SIZE", "Size is " + pc.arraySize()); // Log output: 'Size is 1'
```

Now, even though I have verified that there are indeed two elements in the `ArrayList` in the JSON file, only 1 gets loaded into the object using `fromJson`.

I am serializing these just fine, I would however like to deserialize the `ArrayList<OtherCustomClass>` inside of the `GrandParentClass`, which is inside of the `ParentClass`, in one fell swoop.

Basically I want to serialize `ArrayLists` nested possibly 3 or 4 layers down in this object heirarchy, and deserialize them into 1 ParentClass that contains these nested `ArrayLists<?>`.  How would this be accomplished?

Thanks

Comment: Just out of curiosity why did you choose to use GSON?  I have been using [jackson](http://jackson.codehaus.org/) for the speed of parsing.  I just want to know if it is worth my time looking into GSON.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to do some additional work when you want to deserialize a collection when generics are involved. This is explained [here](https://sites.google.com/site/gson/gson-user-guide#TOC-Serializing-and-Deserializing-Gener).

However, I am not sure how this applies to your case, since you have the collection "nested" within a top-level non-generic class.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class ParentClass {
    public static ArrayList<CustomClass> myList = new ArrayList<CustomClass>();

    private GrandParentClass nested;

    public ParentClass() {
        myList.add(new CustomClass("adsf"));
        myList.add(new CustomClass("fdsa"));

        nested = new GrandParentClass();
    }

    public int arraySize() {
        return myList.size();
    }
}

public class GrandParentClass {


    public GrandParentClass() {
        ParentClass.myList.add(new CustomClass("asdfasdf.."));
        ParentClass.myList.add(new CustomClass("fdsafdsa..."));

    }

    public int arraySize() {
        return ParentClass.myList.size();
    }
}
```

As you are again declaring and iniatilizing same array, so there possibility of getting lost the data. try this one out